# jQuery - select parent object

Tags: jquery, navigation, parent

I've got a nav-structure like

```
<ul class="layer-1">
 <li>
   <ul>
    <li>back</li>
    <li>item-1</li>
    <li>item-2</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>item-2</li>
 <li>item-3</li>
</ul>
```

and i want the back button to take effect on the parent `<ul class="layer-1">`. like changing it to `<ul class="layer-1 active">` if you click on the `<li>back</li>`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use:

```
.closest(".layer-1");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HHhek/)

EDIT: The user now wants to add an 'active' class. Simply change the code in my JSFiddle from 'green' to 'active'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
.closest(".layer-1")
```

or:

```
.find(".layer-1")
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the class on back list and do like this:

```
$('.back').on('click',function(){
  $(this).closest('.layer-1').addClass('active');
  // you wish to use toggleClass instead of addClass
});
```

Or if that your final markup then you can use this:

```
$('.layer-1 ul li:first-child').on('click',function(){
  $(this).closest('.layer-1').addClass('active');
  // you wish to use toggleClass instead of addClass
});
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use the following code:

```
<ul class="layer-1">
 <li>
   <ul class="asd">
    <li class="tee">back</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>...</li>
 <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

And in the js code :
    $('.tee').click(function() {
     console.log($(this).closest('ul').closest('li').parent().attr('class'));
        });